# How to change error class (yii2 form)

Tags: php, html, yii2

I have active form:

```html
<? $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{input}\n{hint}\n{error}",
        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
            'error' => 'help-inline',
            'hint' => '',
        ],
    ],
]);
?>

<div class="control-group">
    <b>Регистрация</b>
        </div>
<?
 echo $form->field($model, 'login', ['options' => ['tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'control-group'],'inputOptions' => array('placeHolder' => 'Логин')]);
 echo $form->field($model, 'password', ['options' => ['tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'control-group'],'inputOptions' => array('placeHolder' => 'Пароль')]);
 echo $form->field($model, 'repassword', ['options' => ['tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'control-group'], 'inputOptions' => array('placeHolder' => 'Повторите пароль')]);
?>


<? ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

If user has entered the wrong data, yii2 adds 'has-error' class, but i need 'error' class. How i can change class? I tried to change value of errorOptions but it did not help.

Comment: I have not added a wrapper because it creates an extra div tags

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem

```html
<? $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{input}\n{hint}\n{error}",
        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
            'error' => 'help-inline',
            'hint' => '',
        ],
    ],
    'errorCssClass' => 'error'
]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change this line :

```
'error' => 'help-inline'
```

to

```
'error' => 'error-inline'
```

Comment: i need to change DIV class which CONTAINS input tag.